# JTable auto resizing to JScrollPane height and width

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I have been reading all over the internet to try to find a solution to my problem.
Can anyone help me. How can I auto resize Jtable's height to fit parent container when there aren't enough rows for scrollbar to show. thanks

UPDATE: code that shows my problem, and how suggested solution is not helping.thanks

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;


public class t extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    t frame = new t();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public t() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        table = new JTable(10,10);
        table. setFillsViewportHeight( true );
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }

}
```

Comment: Post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: *"How can I auto resize Jtable's height to fit parent container when there aren't enough rows for scrollbar to show."*  That doesn't really make sense (to the user) and therefore is inadvisable.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Don't understand why is that. My Jtable is inside JScrollPane/JPanel/BorderLayout.CENTER.... and when i resize my app to fullscreen i get a empty space under my JTable, and that is ugly(to the user)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I auto resize Jtable's height to fit parent container when there aren't enough rows for scrollbar to show.

I think you are looking for:

```
table. setFillsViewportHeight( true );
```

Edit:

> but doesn't seem to work...

Add the following lines of code to your example:

```
contentPane.setBackground(Color.RED);
scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
```

and you will see a red border.

Then remove:

```
table. setFillsViewportHeight( true );
```

and you will see red and blue, indicating that the table height was originally increased.

If you are expecting to see empty cells painted then it won't work. The table can only paint what is in the model. If you want more rows of data painted, then you need to add more rows of data to the model. And if the height decreases you need to remove data from the model.

Of course now you need to track which is "valid" rows of data and which is "filler" rows of data. So you would need to create a custom TableModel to manage this. You would then add a ComponentListener to the table to handle the height changes in the table and then do your manipulation of the TableModel.

Comment: sorry, but doesn't seem to work...will post the update to show its not.thanks