# JTable showing a grey background where there are no rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable

[image]

I put the table in a scrollPanel so that if I add too many rows it still fits in the space i gave it, but when there are few rows, that space is not fully occupied and it shows that grey background. How can I remove it?
Also I used the jTable.setTableHeader(null) instruction but as you can see a small grey row also appears on top, why?
I also set the setting "no borders", but borders are still showing. How do I fix that?

Comment: Since your table appears to have only one column, you might want to consider a [JList](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JList.html) instead.

Comment: That is just an example to show the problem, i actually need a table with two columns.
Well, at least i think that is what I need. My goal is to make something like the youtube search bar, it shows all your last researches and you can remove any of them.

Comment: *How can I remove it?* - what do you mean how can you remove it? What do you expect to see? Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194049/jtable-auto-resizing-to-jscrollpane-height-and-width/28196373#28196373

Comment: @camickr having it transparent and seeing the background image would have been great but having it at least white is more than enough, thanks.
Also I found this to get rid of the scrollPanel border ```jScrollPane1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());```